# Get the right input from barcode scanner

Tags: android

I use Android PDA with barcode scanner. Found out that the key for scanning has keyCode:301. Now I need to  scan barcode only when that (physical keyboard) button is pressed. I need advice how to do it. Because my code doesnt work how it should. The reason is probably in key pressed with that keyCode only takes char of that keyCode. However, my current code prints double values of each number in barcode.
How can I resolve this?

```
  @Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
    Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(e.getKeyCode()));
  //  int hScan = 301;

    if((e.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (e.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) &&(e.getKeyCode() == 301)  )
    {
        System.out.println("Počelo skeinrajje");

    }

    pressedKey = (char) e.getUnicodeChar();
    barcode += pressedKey;

    if (e.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_UP  && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER ) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "barcode--->>>" + barcode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                barcode ="";
    }

    return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its printing double values because you're adding the character on key up and key down.  Choose one, and if its that value immediately return. (either choice is valid, just be consistent).

Also note that some devices will send ACTION_MULTIPLE, which you'll also need to handle if you aren't in control of the scanner hardware choice.

Comment: just changed, still prints double values :(